# Array overwritten instead of creating new value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
while(...){
$foo='somevalue';
 $bar[$foo] = $bar[$foo] + $var;
}
```

$foo can either change or stay the same with each iteration, what i want to do is add all the same values for same $foo, but when i do count after while loop there's just 1.

I want the array count to be the same as number of different $foo values.
How can i change this so its not overwriting?

edit: later on in the file i want to use `foreach ($bar as $key => $value)`

My expectation is that using `$bar[$foo] = $bar[$foo] + $var;` will create new entry in array if $foo value changes

Comment: show your full code. `$var` is not defined

Comment: `$bar[$foo][] = $var;`?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL $var is just some int

Comment: `foo` should be int and increment it by atleast 1 before the next loop cycle , if `foo` is a string than make `$bar[$foo][$i]` where `$i` will increment by one before the next cycle

Comment: @Tabby if i use $bar[$foo][$i] how would i use it in foreach?

Comment: @grasshopper see my answer with demo. You can use foreach for stable iteration

Comment: @grasshopper your dealing with associative array and `$bar[$foo][$i]` makes it an associative array. foreach is used for associative array

Answer (score 0):

You can use ;

```
$a = array("10","10","10","60", "2", "2","70");


foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    $bar[$v][] = $k;
}

foreach ($bar as $key => $val) {
    echo count($bar[$key]) . "\n";
}
```

Here is working demo: **[phpfiddle](http://codepad.org/j5VN7USH)**

Comment: No matter if i put $bar[$foo][$i] or $bar[$i][$foo], $foo gets overwritten, so no new set added to array, just overwritten

Comment: So, my answer is not suitable for your question?

Comment: @grasshopper You might not be incrementing `$i`

Answer (score 0):

ok found solution:
problem was that array wasnt being overwritten just being reset inside loop with `$bar=array();`so just added `is_array` check

```
 while(...){ 
    if (!is_array($bar))
        $bar=array();         
        $foo='somevalue';
        $bar[$foo] = $bar[$foo] + $var;
        }
```

thanks for the help